# Strange behavior of python's exec function

Tags: python

I think that below code fully describes the problem. Why in the Test2 function x has not been defined? Why the Test3 function does not return an error?

```
>>> def Test1():
exec('x=2')
print(str(x))


>>> Test1()
2
>>> def Test2():
global x
exec('x=2')
print(str(x))


>>> Test2()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
Test2()
File "<pyshell#38>", line 4, in Test2
print(str(x))
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

>>> def Test3():
global x
x=2
print(str(x))

>>> Test3()
2
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Don't use `global`, and don't use `exec`; they lead to badly designed code, and in the case of `exec`, insecure code.

Comment: I was trying to load my dictionary based databese from a txt file :)

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Instead, store your database as JSON, and load it with `mydata = json.load(open('mydb.txt'))` or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by @SanSS is correct, as is the comment by @Colin Dunklau, but I wanted to add a bit more info.  One thing that may trip you up is that the `global x` in Test2 does *not* carry through to the exec-ed code.  So the exec creates a *local* variable `x`, while the `print x` tries to read a global variable.  These two examples may be helpful. . .

Here by passing one dict, you tell exec to use that as globals *and* locals, so the exec assigns to globals:

```
>>> def Test2():
...     global x
...     exec 'x=2' in globals()
...     print(str(x))
>>> Test2()
2
```

Here by including the global declaration in the exec-ed code, you make the exec assign to the global, which the print statement then reads:

```
>>> def Test2():
...     global x
...     exec('global x; x=2')
...     print(str(x))
>>> Test2()
2
```

To reiterate, however, it's usually not a good idea to use `exec`.  It can be good to play around with stuff like this sometimes just to understand how Python works, but there are few cases where this is a good way to actually accomplish something with your code.

Answer (score 2):

In function `Test2`, when you declare `global x` you are stating that `x` is a global variable, so Python will search for it in the global namespace.
As there is no `x` variable defined in the global namespace the `NameError` is raised.

If you read [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) you can see that the `eval` function is not affected by the `global` statement, so in `Test2` the `exec` is creating  a new local variable named `x` with value 2, but not global; the `print` is affected by the `global` statement and searches for the `x` in the global namespace where it doesn't exist. In Test3 the `x=2` statement is affected by the `global` statement thus creating a global variable named x with value 2.

Comment: I dont get it :( Why does the Test3 function work? exec('x=2') should be the same as x=2

Comment: @user1354439, see my answer for explanation.  The global statement does not carry through to the exec-ed code, so `exec('x=2')` is not the same as `x=2`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I was editing my comment to explain that when you answered. I couldn't explain it as simple as you, though :P